# Output lines that are unique for pattern 1 and have the highest value for pattern 2

Tags: awk

I want to use the sed or awk commands to print only lines from a list that are unique in terms of pattern 1 and have the highest value for pattern 2. The input is a list of filenames that are software versions for specific models. Both the model number and the software version are included in the filename. The patters are as so:

`a,b_x.y.z_` or  `a,b_x.y_`

Pattern 1 is `a,b` (Model)
Pattern 2 is `x.y.z` (Software Version)

For every unique version of `a,b` I want to find the latest version of `x.y.z` or `x.y`

N.B. I don't want to search by time created or modified etc… this has to be done by the strings for Software Version and Model Number

Comment: while it might be possible to do what you're asking in sed, it will be at the outside limits of what any normal sed user could understand. `awk` is very well suited to such a task. Consider editing to question to allow for awk answers. Good lukc.

Comment: Thanks, there are already some sed commands in the original script I am editing so thought it best to stick with that but if awk is the right tool for the job I'll be happy to use it!

Answer (score 1):

Like @shellter says `sed` really would not be suited for this. I would use `awk` or something like that. With version numbers each of the sub-numbers would need to be compared numerically. You could try something like this:

```
   awk '
      BEGIN{
        FS=OFS="_"
      }
      { 
        # Use "." to split current and version numbers into field arrays
        m=split($2,New,/\./)
        n=split(Version[$1],Current,/\./)

        # loop from 1 through the highest number of fields (whichever of the two versions contains the most fields)
        for(i=1; i<=(m>n?m:n); i++) { 

          # they are unequal no need to compare further fields, if the new one is higher then replace.
          if(New[i]!=Current[i]){
            if(New[i]>Current[i]) Version[$1]=$2
            next
          }
        }
      } 
      END{
        for(i in Version)print i,Version[i]
      }
    ' file
```

---

I made a couple of modifications to print the last part and ignore the directory tree in the comparison. See if this works:

```
awk -F_ '
  { 
    # save current record
    p=$0
    # remove directory info
    sub(/.*\//,x)
    # Use "." to split current and version numbers into array
    m=split($2,New,/\./)
    n=split(Version[$1],Current,/\./)

    # loop from 1 through the highest number of fields (whichever of the two versions contains the most fields)
    for(i=1; i<=(m>n?m:n); i++) { 

      # they are unequal no need to compare further fields, if the new one is higher then replace.
      if(New[i]!=Current[i]) {
        if(New[i]>Current[i]) {
          Version[$1]=$2
          Line[$1]=p
        }
        next
      }
    }
  } 
  END{
    for(i in Version)print Line[i]
  }
'  file
```

Comment: This is getting close @Scrutinizer! This script took a batch of 56 lines and turned it into 28, all of the omissions are correct. There are still some extra files in there that are not being compared as we had hoped, but I think that is down to my framing of the question rather than your script :)

Comment: Two things stick out. The first is that after the x.y.z or x.y the end of the filename is Backup.dat and this is not getting printed....as these are hyper-links I kinda need that bit at the end. The other thing is that in many cases the directory path to the files is different for each revision of software.....so we might see: **ttp://version/vol1/volvo2,6_1.1.1_Backup.dat**
 and **ttp://version/volvo3/volvo2,6_3.0.4_Backup.dat** getting printed when only the second one should be with it having the latest software.